# Як перекласти "prompt engineering" та "prompt engineer"?

Tags: переклад, терміни

З появою таких інструментів як ChatGPT та Midjourney, з'явилась концепція `prompt engineering`:

> Prompt engineering - концепція штучного інтелекту, суть якого полягає в тому, щоб формувати запити до великих мовних моделей у вигляді запитання, а не програмних інструкцій.

Фактично, це людина, яка створює `prompt` (запит, підказку) до ChatGPT, Midjourney та інших подібних інструментів.

Я зустрічав варіанти `інженер оперативного управління` і `оперативний інженер`, але ці переклади ніяк не асоціюються з суттю роботи.

Comment: Напевно офіційного перекладу що не існує. Я думаю буде досить зрозуміло якщо перекласти: "інженерія запитів для мовних моделей"

Comment: Не підходить, бо Midjourney  - не мовна модель, але там prompts теж є.

Answer (score 4):

Інженерія запитів для ШІ, інженер запитів для ШІ

Comment: Або ж просто «інженер запитів»

Answer (score 0):

Я би йшов від слова «запит»: запитувач, запитник, запитовець, запитовий інженер тощо

Comment: Плюсую `запитовий інженер`